# Weka - How can I improve J48 performance?

Tags: performance, weka, j48

I'm working on a data mining project when I need to be able to predict chances of success on a Kickstarter project funding.

I've used a kickstarter dataset which i've found on Kaggle, and i've cleaned all the noisy data, deleted irrelevant attributes and added another useful attributes.

Now I have about 320K instances and 6 attributes.

After running J48 algorithm, I'm getting 65.07% correctly classified instances and 68.7% average roc area.
I have to get this performance improved but I dont know how.

It's a college project so I have specific rules: I can only change the Confidence Factor and NumMinObj of the algorithm.
I've spending a lot of time trying every combination.

What can I do else? Maybe something in my dataset is problematic?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of instances, but few attributes. If you can't add more attributes then probably you already got the best result you can have with `J48` trees, and feature selection is useless. You probably have to use a more complex classification algorithm such as `RandomForest`.